# Analog and digital audio output at the same time

Tags: sound, hardware, headphones, speakers

My speakers use a digital input, but my headphones use an analog input.  I have them both plugged in, and when I want to use the headphones I just turn off the speakers and switch on the headphones.  I know that simultaneous output on digital and analog is supported by the hardware, because it worked fine in Windows XP.  But on Ubuntu, I seem to only get one at a time, depending on which setting is selected in the combo box located at `System -> Preferences -> Sound -> Hardware`.

How can I get simultaneous analog and digital output without having to switch the profile every time?  I'm on Ubuntu 11.04 and it's an HDA Intel chip.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We have the optional application [paprefs](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=paprefs) that allows to install a virtual output device to pulseaudio. This enables simultaneous output to all attached sound cards/devices:

[image: paprefs]

The additionally created audio output device for *simultaneous output* may be selected in the *"Output"* tab from pulseaudio sound preferences menu:

[image]

---

From the command line we can also load the device for simultaneous output without having to run **paprefs** by

```
pacmd load-module module-combine-sink
# pacmd load-module module-combine # for PulseAudio < 1.0
```

Put this line (without pacmd) in your `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to load this device at startup.

Comment: great , it worked !

Comment: Do you know how to do this without installing this application? I'm guessing it should be only a single command line operation.

Comment: @l0b0: see edit for this.

Comment: This works, though sometimes, such as after suspend/resume, the sound goes out again through one source and I have to select the synchronous output again. Plus sometimes the audio is out of sync, but this I can solve easily pausing and resuming the video.

Comment: @JoseGómez: both may be a timing issue, e.g. a sink is not yet ready on resuming after suspend. Hard to get around this - at least I don't have any good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't work anymore, at least from ubuntu 16.04 LTS (maybe even more, but I am not sure). What works is the following (tested in ubuntu 17.10): https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples

Specifically add the following to your `/etc/pulse/default.pa`

```
### Load analog device
load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,0
load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=combined
set-default-sink combined
```

Comment: Sorry. Made the corrections.