# How to Pass/Record audio output as an input device?

Tags: pulseaudio, output, audio-recording

I used to use a mixer of some kind and I can't remember which...

I would like to record audio from the output, without leaving the computer. I remember in the Jaunty days you could easily enable different inputs and outputs as passthroughs of sorts from the sound preferences.

How can I achieve this functionality on 10.04 and beyond?

I don't favor any particular way, be it digital, analog, pulse or alsa... I can support any solution.

Comment: @Jay For simultaneous recording, I simply used Sound Recorder's File→New option to start a second recorder. That showed up in pavucontrol as a separate stream and I set it to record from my microphone.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Wow, that was quick...I feel guilty for posting this, but I have been struggling to find an answer so I hope this helps someone else:

Taken from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1440833 does exactly what I was looking for...tested and working. The term I used to find the solution was "record internal audio" rather than output/input keywords.

To sum it up:

- Install pavucontrol (PulseAudio Volume Control) using apt-get or the Ubuntu Software Center.
- Open PulseAudio Volume Control. It should be in the applications menu under Sound and Video.
- Open Sound Recorder and start recording. Playing any sound at this point would be helpful, as your level indicator should react once you have finished.
- Go to the "Recording" tab in the PulseAudio Volume Control window.
- Make sure that "Applications" is selected in the drop down menu on the "Recording" tab.
- Choose "Monitor of Internal Audio Analog Atereo" from the "Record Stream from" menu in the Sound Recorder entry of the application list.

Comment: Hey TryTryAgain, this was really useful and got me on the right track. I can now successfully record my audio output. I'm wondering if you have had any luck recording *both* input and output *simultaneously*?

Comment: @Jay you should open a new question for that, to better help others in the future. http://askubuntu.com/questions/57319/analog-and-digital-audio-output-at-the-same-time will help with simultaneous output (and has been a help to me) not sure if that can help for recording...doubtful, as far as simultaneous recording of input...I have not ever tested or come across anything, sorry.

Comment: Bonus tip, make sure `"Monitor of …"` is _unmuted_ on the `"Input Devices"` tab. You should be able to see the level display moving.

Answer (score 1):

In case VLC does not recognize the `pulse://` protocol to record the pulseaudio stream, install the pulse plugin using `apt-get install vlc-plugin-pulse`.