# Make a USB device show up as an input and output device

Tags: 12.10, command-line, usb, alsa, input-devices

**What am I attempting to do?**

I am trying to make my Line6 Toneport UX1 (hooked up via USB) an output and input device at the same time.

**Why am I trying to do this?**

For those of you that don't know, Line6 Toneport UX1 is an interface/intermediary that allows any instrument and/or microphone hooked into it to be sent to a software effects board and/or to another program (e.g. Ableton Live) for recording.

**What have I done?**

First, I went to the fabled Ubuntu sound control panel to change my audio devices.  Toneport shows up in the output tab, but not in the input tab.  Hmmm...

Second, I attempted to use PulseAudio Volume Control (yes, I referred to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171287/how-to-pass-record-audio-output-as-an-input-device) question) to pass an output device as an input device.  This was not successful as it did not actually change the properties of the USB device nor was I able to hear myself speak through the microphone or my classical guitar.

Third, I attempted to use AlsaMixer.  By pressing <kbd>f6</kbd>, I was able to switch the sound card from the default Intel sound card to the Line6 Toneport.  The mixer looks like the following for playback...

[image: Playback]

When I change the middle channel to "Instrument" and turn the volume up on my Toneport, I am able to hear my classical guitar.  Success!... sort of.

However, when I press <kbd>f4</kbd> to display capture capabilities, the following pops up...

[image: Capture]

---

**`aplay -l`**

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: VT1708S Analog [VT1708S Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 2: VT1708S HP [VT1708S HP]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: TonePortUX1 [TonePort UX1], device 0: TonePort UX1 [TonePort UX1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

---

**`arecord -l`**

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: VT1708S Analog [VT1708S Analog]
  Subdevices: 2/2
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
card 1: TonePortUX1 [TonePort UX1], device 0: TonePort UX1 [TonePort UX1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

---

**`lsusb -v -d 0e41:`**

```
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.00
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x0e41 Line6, Inc.
  idProduct          0x4141 
  bcdDevice            0.01
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          124
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              498mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0000  1x 0 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0000  1x 0 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x00c0  1x 192 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x00c8  1x 200 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       2
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x00b4  1x 180 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x00bc  1x 188 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       3
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0120  1x 288 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x012c  1x 300 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       4
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x010e  1x 270 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x011a  1x 282 bytes
        bInterval               1
```

---

If that wasn't enough to drive the point home, I opened up Gearbox (the software used for moulding guitar tones and whatnot) only to be disappointed by a blinking USB symbol in the bottom of the window.  That indicated that Toneport was not detected nor plugged in.

**So what the heck is my question again?**

How do I change the rules, properties or whatever you'd like to call it to make Toneport an output **AND** input device at the same time?  Is this even possible?  Solutions could be done programatically through terminal, through the use of a GUI... I am open to anything.

**Other resources**

- [Installation instructions](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-a-line6-guitarport-or-toneport-ux1-or-gx.html)

Comment: Please show the output of "`aplay -l`" and "`arecord -l`".

Comment: @CL. The question has been updated as per your request :)

Comment: Does "`arecord -D plughw:TonePortUX1 -f dat test.wav`" record something?

Comment: @CL. Yes it does!  It records a little riff I played on the guitar.

Comment: Please show the output of "`lsusb -v -d 0e41:`".

Comment: @CL. Updated again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PulseAudio does not show an input device because the UX1 uses an uncommon sample format.
As shown with `arecord`, the input device actually exists and works if you do not use PulseAudio.

Please visit the [Line6 Linux USB driver page](http://www.tanzband-scream.at/line6/) and read the driver documentation.

Comment: I've attempted both methods (RPM and source) but I receive error messages for both.  The RPM method says `error: Failed build dependencies: kernel-source is needed by line6usb-0.8.1-1.x86_64` and upon executing `make install` for source I receive a message that says that a "build" sub directory does not exist.  I've already installed the most recent driver source code from sourceforge so I'm not too sure what the problem is... I mean, build doesn't exist but I wonder why...

Comment: The driver is already included in Ubuntu. You are supposed to read the documentation.

Comment: I've gone through the entire documentation, believe me.  I haven't the foggiest idea why the `build` folder does not exist if it's supposed to be included (according to the documentation).  Regardless, I'm going to accept this answer.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: That documentation is outdated as far as building is concerned, but you do *not* need to do this anyway.