# Multiple sound outputs with hdmi and speakers. It is possible? [Ubuntu 12.10]

Tags: 12.10, hdmi, speakers

There is a way to configure a simultaneous output from hdmi and speakers sound?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play sound through two or more outputs/devices](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78174/play-sound-through-two-or-more-outputs-devices) and answer to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/57319/analog-and-digital-audio-output-at-the-same-time) for a command line solution.

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate of that question. If your question is different, edit this one to narrow your question down, and we'll vote to re-open it.