# Volume "equalizer"/volume control

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, volume-control, equalizer

Is there any program that can equalise/normalise audio output to a preset level real time?

I dont want to disturb my neighbors at nights when I am watching youtube videos sometimes they are a series of clips which have different volume

so one clip is loud at e.g 10% and the next is barely audible at 30% volume bar then the one that follows could be earbraking at 30% volume bar etc

volume bar = youtube player volume bar.

So is there any program that can automatically lower the volume if it exceeds a preset limit in real time?

I am not talking about controlling the youtube volume bar per se (I suppose that would be harder) but a program that monitors the audio volume that gets outputed from the audio chip's green minijack out and balanace it to a certain volume.

Comment: Not sure about Ubuntu here but that's typically something you could fix with some kind of audio compression.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range_compression Sometimes it helps to throw around these terms when looking for something. It's usually just referred to as "audio compression" or a "compressor" to limit the volume in decibels.

Comment: I guess this could also be described as a limiter.

Comment: You would want extremely steep or fast minimal attack and decay. There is a complicated similar post here which may help you as sort of a work around, although, I do understand that you are looking for an easier solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/95716/automatically-adjust-the-volume-based-on-content

Comment: Also, see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/659582/real-time-volume-leveling-audio-outputs?rq=1