# possible to route audio to two soundcards in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, pulseaudio, soundcard

Wondering if it is at all possible to route one audio stream from an application to two different hardware sources? I have 2 sound cards. Using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Something like this http://askubuntu.com/questions/57319/analog-and-digital-audio-output-at-the-same-time?